# Redo foreach to .stream().map

Tags: java, for-loop, collections, java-8, java-stream

currently I have two lists `List<MonthlyFeePayment> monthlyFeePaymentList` and a new one `List<FeePaymentStatusRequest> request = new ArrayList<>();`. What I need is to go through all `monthlyFeePaymentList` elements and fill my `request` list. `FeePaymentStatus` consists from `monthlyFeePaymentId` and `sourceSystem`(which is always the same).

My current implementation:

```
List<FeePaymentStatusRequest> request = new ArrayList<>();
    for (MonthlyFeePayment monthlyFeePayment : monthlyFeePaymentList) {
        request.add(new FeePaymentStatusRequest(monthlyFeePayment.getMonthlyFeePaymentId().toString(), "BGW"));
    }
```

I want to re do it using `.stream().map()`, but I can't figure it out. It should be pretty easy considering that it's only two lists. But I don't know which list should go first, `request.stream()` or `monthlyFeePaymentList.stream()`? Could you explain how the `Stream#map` works in this specific situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one you're iterating over:

```
List<FeePaymentStatusRequest> request = monthlyFeePaymentList.stream()
    .map(monthlyFeePayment -> new FeePaymentStatusRequest(monthlyFeePayment.getMonthlyFeePaymentId().toString(), "BGW"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can collect it then without creating a new list explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

The `map` operation of `Stream` would transform the object from `MonthlyFeePayment` to that of `FeePaymentStatusRequest`, given the way you've already defined in the `for` loop code.

```
List<FeePaymentStatusRequest> request = monthlyFeePaymentList
          .stream() // Stream<MonthlyFeePayment>
          .map(monthlyFeePayment -> new FeePaymentStatusRequest(
                   monthlyFeePayment.getMonthlyFeePaymentId().toString(), "BGW")) // Stream<FeePaymentStatusRequest>
          .collect(Collectors.toList()); // List<FeePaymentStatusRequest>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create the output `List` explicitly.

`Stream` over your input `List`, `map` each `MonthlyFeePayment` to a `FeePaymentStatusRequest` instance, and `collect` to a `List`:

```
List<FeePaymentStatusRequest> request = 
    monthlyFeePaymentList.stream()
                         .map(monthlyFeePayment -> new FeePaymentStatusRequest(monthlyFeePayment.getMonthlyFeePaymentId().toString(), "BGW"))
                         .collect(Collectors.toLis());
```